# SQL Server 2008: Filtering Out Duplicate Rows Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Thanks to everyone who helped me with my last question. This is a similar question, but now I have a better idea of what I want. Again I'm using MS SQL Server 2008, and I'm trying to figure out a query that is a little beyond my week of SQL experience.

Right now I have the following simple query

```
SELECT pl.val, pl.txt_val, pl.id
FROM dm.labs pl
  WHERE pl.lab_nm = 'CK (CPK)' 
    AND pl.val < 999999;
    AND pl.val IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY pl.val;
```

In this table, each row corresponds to the results of a patient's lab value. The problem is that for some patients, there are rows that are actually multiple copies of the same lab reading. There is a column `pl.lab_filed_dts` (datetime data type) giving the date the lab was taken.

What I want to do is:

*Edit:* if two (or more) rows have the same `id`, the same `val`, and the same `lab_filed_dts`, regardless of their values in any other column, I want to return `val`, `txt_val`, and `id` from only one of the rows (it doesn't matter which one).

*Edit:* if two rows have the same `id`, the same `val`, and the same day portion (but not necessarily time) of `lab_filed_dts` AND the time portion of `lab_filed_dts` for one of them is midnight, I want to return `val`, `txt_val`, and `id` from the row whose `lab_filed_dts` time is not midnight.

Thanks again for everyone's help!

Comment: When you have two (or more) rows, how do you determine which txt_val to select?

Comment: Is there a primary key on this table?

Comment: Tom: there is a primary key, `lab_id`. 

Lins: either I don't understand your question or I don't understand how SELECT works.

What I meant to say was: if two (or more) rows have the same `id`, the same `val`, and the same `lab_filed_dts`, regardless of their values in any other column, I want to return `val`, `txt_val`, and `id` from only one of the rows (it doesn't matter which one). Does this help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
SELECT pl.val, pl.txt_val, pl.id
FROM dm.labs pl
  WHERE pl.lab_nm = 'CK (CPK)' 
    AND pl.val < 999999;
    AND pl.val IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  pl.val, pl.txt_val, pl.id, cast(lab_filed_dts as date)
HAVING lab_filed_dts =  max(lab_filed_dts)
ORDER BY pl.val;
```

/* changed `pl.vak` to `pl.val` as you can't order on a column not in the `select` and I assumed it was just a type*/

Comment: @jmoreno: I hope you don't mind that I edited your post. If you indent each line of a block of code by four spaces you'll get the nice formatting.

Comment: I don't think that this will work. If two labs have different txt_val values, they will both appear in the results even if the important columns are the same.

Comment: I think another problem with this is that if use `HAVING lab_filed_dts = max(lab_filed_dts)` then I'll only get the most recent CK lab for each patient. Patients have multiple labs done over time and I want to see all of the lab results. What I'm trying to get rid of are rows in the table that are multiple copies of a single lab value, that is, for some reason readings for a patient were taken once but a nurse entered the results into the data records twice.

Comment: @raoulcousins: What Tom is looking for is a natural key, some combination of one or more of the RELEVANT fields that uniquely identify the row.  An identify field is a surrogate key and while that can be useful, you should always try to identify a natural key.  In this case, if you could know when the lab was completed, that would provide your natural key, it wouldn't matter when the data was entered, the time it was completed would be unique, and you could thus prevent duplicates from ever being entered.

Comment: @raoulcousins: I've changed the query so that you'll only get the last lab of the day. I didn't do the midnight check, because that would make the query a lot more complex and I'm not sure of the actual utility.  Tell me what you think of the current version...

Comment: @jmoreno: I'll have to look at the data more carefully, but there doesn't seem to be a combination of relevant keys that I can consistently use as a unique identifier. That's the big problem with this messy data set. Your change is very helpful. If I can pull one lab for each day this is a huge help. Where does the difficulty come from in the midnight thing? Would it be any easier if it didn't matter which row is returned if one is midnight?

Comment: @jmoreno: Also, are there any books you recommend so I can really learn to do this myself? I've read through O'Reilly Learning SQL, but maybe I need something more SQL Server specific.

Comment: @jmoreno: this one gives me the error Column 'dm.labs.lab_filed_dts' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. There was also an unrelated extra semicolon at `AND pl.val < 999999` but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm trying the second method now.